# On the Cylon capital, who are the silver-robed aliens?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-1978

In the Battlestar Galactica episode *[The Living Legend part 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0519753/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm)*, the colonials attack a Cylon city on the planet Gamoray. As the attack starts, there's shot of a crowd of Cylons and other aliens running away.

[image]

(From 27:45 on the Netflix episode.)

There's reference to Cylon civilians earlier in this story, but there's also a mention of a previous population on Gamoray. Who are these silver-suited figures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only non-warrior variant of Cylon I can find information about is the IL-series (or Imperious Leader) http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/IL-series - but the Cylons in your picture look to be another type again...

Correction:

They are "civilian" models: http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Cylon_civilian

It seems that the Cylon Empire (or The Alliance) is quite an old civilization http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Cylons_(TOS) and it would make sense for there to be some kind of differentiation in models and function.